# What is WebResource.axd?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have troubles with blowery web and WebResource.axd.

What is WebResource.axd?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

WebResource.axd provides access to embedded resources within a project. It's a handler that enables control and page developers to download resources that are embedded in an assembly to the end user.

You include WebResources in your AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("Project.Styles.Main.css", "text/css")]
```

Then you can get an include path for your Page using the following code:

```
string includeLocation = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(),    
    "Project.Styles.Main.css");
```

Then to add the above file (which is a CSS file in this case):

```
LiteralControl include = new LiteralControl(
    String.Format(includeTemplate, includeLocation));

((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead)Page.Header).Controls.Add(include);
```

Then you'll end up seeing references within your page source such as the following:

```
/WebResource.axd?d=PhPk80h_UWEcbheb-NHNP5WshV_47UOpWqAOl1_li
    UFfN4cNofL74cFlQ1fvpFSf0&t=632573240669964903
```

Comment: How/where is the `includeTemplate` declared?

Answer (score 10):

It's a generated HttpHandler file. Most likely you have some embedded resource in your ASP.NET application, or one of the third party components you use. To transport these in a transparent way ASP.NET makes use of this approach where the correct resource can be identified depending on the passed in querystring. For example:

```
WebResource.axd?d=PhPk80h_UWEcbheb-NHNP5WshV_47UOpWqAOl1_liUFfN4cNofL74cFlQ1fvpFSf0&t=632573240669964903
```

Taken from [Using WebResource.axd for embedded resources](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeff/archive/2005/07/18/419842.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Its for embedded resources.

[Working with Web Resources in ASP.NET 2.0](https://www.cnblogs.com/easyjacky/articles/1103952.html)