# WebResource.axd A script on this page may be busy

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

I'm getting this error when I open aspx page in firefox having some java script files.

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: http://:3370/WebResource.axd?d=sqKLILs3i83RlYFBm7crljGNdcw8tYbuunzdSE8DA_W1IEnfv8m0bZyf-yURpWEL7SpXYN_qpWFfaRvuyWUx8ZRSOcC-rMZpejapIQL501TDYfoqWX1xBD8kSPFE3dBh7FcctPH0qHA7O2IfWhfH3HAm2ghCy-TlXkt0O5EMUU8rscGj0&t=635031027038792083:20

Comment: That is an invalid URL, anyway could you post the source code of this script?

Comment: url is http://localhost:3370/WebResource.axd?....

Comment: but I don't have WebResource.axd file in my solution

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318092/what-is-webresource-axd (I'm a java developer, so I don't have knowledge about asp.net)

Comment: got solution problem was in date format changes from dd-MM-yyyy ddd to dd-MM-yyyy

Comment: @SachinPanchal Care to elaborate on your solution by adding it as an answer (and extending the benefit to others)?