# WebResource.axd 404's

Tags: asp.net, .net, webresource.axd

I get this error many times a day showing up in my event viewer. It generates 404's. I have never actually seen it when browsing the site and never had anyone contact me about getting that error either. I am trying to decide if it is something serious or just normal behavior because a search engine is crawling the site or something. Should I be concerned?

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 10/29/2013 7:46:55 AM 
Event time (UTC): 10/29/2013 11:46:55 AM 
Event ID: 770a2052e5f64d1d9bced11f85dc5258 
Event sequence: 3663 
Event occurrence: 92 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/5/ROOT-6-130274824589807154 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\webs\GregHowlett.com\ 
    Machine name: XLHOST-OF7SCMKU

Process information: 
    Process ID: 5492 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\GregHowlett.com

Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Session state is not available in this context.
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.get_Session()
   at ASP.global_asax.Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs E)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Request information: 
    Request URL: http://www.greghowlett.com/WebResource.axd?d=eaEsW1VJ0NkQAOZyGROQvoqBSuXiiNQEj5h5BFT5JhWHeRYzpsB3S3kQNwRnDTTsqdN4g096MEjl2bD9ksb7BYVHe4qsARUqLIF3iTli30E1&t=635090765518590119 
    Request path: /WebResource.axd 
    User host address: 41.71.154.2 
    User:
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\GregHowlett.com

Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 58 
    Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\GregHowlett.com 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Web.HttpApplication.get_Session()
   at ASP.global_asax.Application_AcquireRequestState(Object sender, EventArgs E)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Custom event details:

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read Session values within `global_asax.Application_AcquireRequestState`, which is called for `axd` handler too, while they have state disabled. So it is not dangerous but for clarifying situation, you can check in global_asax something like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf(".axd") > 0
```

and do not use Session in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out those articles:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1658831.aspx

and

[What is WebResource.axd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318092/what-is-webresource-axd)

---

So, the cause of the problem might be in your case relatively to configuration, as well as IIS application pool pipeline mode etc.

But generally if you don't use the resources from the WebResource.axd (neither explicitly nor implicitly (in meaning, some other component)), then you should not be so worrying.