# ASP.NET WebResource.axd 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, webresource

I have an asp.net webpage with an AJAX calendar. The calendar's webresource.axd has started returning error 404. I can't think of something I've recently changed. Not the page, nor the web.config, and not in the .net framework.

I have a (supposedly) identical test site on the same server with an identical page that DOES work!

Maybe I could find the problem by finding the difference between the pages? (the actual page codes have NO difference, but maybe something in the environment?)
Is there some kind of IIS cache I could clear that is maybe corrupt?

The AJAX is registered as usual:

The server is Windows server 2008, .NET 4.5 framework. ISS 7.

Please help! thanks.

Comment: The AJAX is registered as usual:   <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

Comment: check these references - [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470080/webresource-axd-not-found), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885389/webresource-axd-404s), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435311/asp-net-webresource-axd-call-404-error-how-to-know-which-assembly-resource-is), [Web Resources Troubleshooting](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/general-information/troubleshooting/web-resources-troubleshooting)