# Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined on ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

I want use ajax on [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/) platform. For that I use [ScriptManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx). Simply I add this script with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) after when "[document is ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)".

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {

    // sync
    {{scopeName}}_init();

    // async

    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (sender, args) {
        {{scopeName}}_init();
    });

});
```

And then such a mysterious [javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) error happened.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Sys is not defined

Q what I have wrong if javascript stop working after first request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is not skip "[Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb311028(v=vs.100).aspx)" using [undefined](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/) condition

```javascript
if (typeof(Sys) !== 'undefined') {
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (sender, args) {
        {{scopeName}}_init();
    });
}
```

For the postback we init function just if document is ready - sync section.

For ajax request in ScriptManager block we need to register init function on "add_pageLoaded". After that everytime script works fine at first request - async section.

Most important neglected step is register also "[add_endRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb383810(v=vs.100).aspx)", and that fix the problem.

Whole example code:

```javascript
$(document).ready(function () {

    // sync
    console.log("sync");
    {{scopeName}}_init();

    // async

    pageRequestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    pageRequestManager.add_endRequest({{scopeName}}_onAsyncEndRequest);
    pageRequestManager.add_pageLoaded({{scopeName}}_onAsyncPageLoaded);


});

function {{scopeName}}_onAsyncEndRequest(sender, args) {
    console.log("async end");
    console.log(args);
}
function {{scopeName}}_onAsyncPageLoaded(sender, args) {
    console.log("async start");
    {{scopeName}}_init();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across this problem myself so I figured I would type this up to help someone who might be going through the same/similar issue.

What I found out was that when VS deployed the application, and I started running the app on my production server, my browser was looking for `ScriptResource.axd` (for ASP.NET AJAX) and `WebResource.axd`, and not finding either file in the root directory.

More on these files: [What is WebResource.axd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318092/what-is-webresource-axd)