# Why Routes.Ignoreroutes("{resource}.axd/{*pathinfo}") not deliberately necessary in webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

```
    Routes.Ignoreroutes("{resource}.axd/{*pathinfo}")
```

is deliberately added in Routeconfig class to ignore scriptresource.axd  or webresource.axd  in MVC.NET . But why we dont need such statements in webforms  . I know we can add such statements in

```
     void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

but we dont need to do it in Webforms . Or will it be a good practice to add such statements in webforms .

Comment: here is the thing , you should know about the web forms. there is page life cycle in web forms whereas mvc doesn't have page life cycle. it supports request life cycle. that's why it has routes and web pages doesn't have routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AXD files are not true files (exist in physical context), they're just registered aliases in `AssemblyResourceLoader`. ASP.NET by default uses `ScriptResource.axd` & `WebResource.axd` in internal context provided by HTTP handling routines.

To prevent passing AXD requests (which is request for non-existent file) to any controllers, `RouteCollection.IgnoreRoute` will ignore any request pointed to those AXD files, implied in [ASP.NET Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx) article:

> If you want routing to handle all requests, even requests that point
>   to files, you can overwrite the default behavior by setting the
>   `RouteExistingFiles` property of the `RouteCollection` object to true.
>   When you set this value to true, all requests that match a defined
>   pattern are handled by routing.
>
> You can also specify that routing should not handle certain URL
>   requests. You prevent routing from handling certain requests by
>   defining a route and specifying that the `StopRoutingHandler` class
>   should be used to handle that pattern. When a request is handled by a
>   `StopRoutingHandler` object, the `StopRoutingHandler` object blocks any
>   additional processing of the request as a route. Instead, the request
>   is processed as an ASP.NET page, Web service, or other ASP.NET
>   endpoint.

Hence, if someone requested e.g. `example.com/WebResource.axd?d=XXXXX&t=ZZZZZZ`, it might returning particular code snippet of any embedded resources in certain assembly file, which *only used by webforms* - not in MVC.

If you're examining web.config file in `%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version number]\Config`, there exists `WebResource` & other AXD paths like this:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add path="eurl.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" validate="True" />
    <add path="trace.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler" validate="True" />
    <add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True" />
    <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False" />
    <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="False"/>
    <add path="*.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" validate="True" />
    ...
</httpHandlers>
```

Note that webforms often uses AXD aliases as embedded resource container from particular assembly which later rendered by ASPX pages, since server controls utilize assembly files to store pre-defined scripts for running through page life cycles. However, MVC itself is HTTP handler which serves request with similar manner like AXD aliases, and since MVC pulls resource files directly rather than using embedded resources (there is no such things like calling `System.Web.UI.WebResource` or `System.Web.UI.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType, [resource path])` in MVC), request to AXD aliases can be safely ignored.

Additional references:

[Just Where Is WebResource.axd?](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/10/28/just-where-is-webresource-axd.aspx)

[What is WebResource.axd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318092/what-is-webresource-axd)